# Unique messages from a kafka topic with in a time interval

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a kafka topic to which 1500 message/sec are produced by different producers with each message having two fixed keys RID and Date, (there are other keys to which are varying for each message)

Is there a way to introduce a delay of 1 min in the topic and consume only unique messages in the 1 min window.

Example - In a minute there could be around 90K message in which there could be 1000(random value) message with RID as 1 and Date as 1st Jan 2020. 
`{"RID": "1" , "Date": "2020-01-01", ....}`

I would like to consume only 1 message among 1000(any one among 1000 at random) after 1 minute is completed.

Note: There are 3 partitions for the topic.

Comment: I hope i am clear now. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

What you want seems not to be possible. The brokers cannot deliver message based on your business logic, but they can only deliver *all* messages.

However, you could implement a client side cache to "de-duplicate" the messages accordingly, and only *process*  a sub-set of the messages after "de-duplication".

Comment: Got your point, Thanks I was exploring if there is something available in server side for optimisation.

Comment: Thanks @matthias, Can you please share the code for the same? I am not using confluent spring-cloud-stream and kafka-streams binder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure about your question, but it seems you need the [compaction log](http://cloudurable.com/blog/kafka-architecture-log-compaction/index.html)

It will remove the oldest messages from the topic, only need to configure the compaction for the topic and use as identifier the RID record.

Hope this can help you

Comment: But i have a consumer running continuously which will consume the duplicate message even before compaction